# Laravel 5.4 - Eager Loading Child and Grandchild with Select Both

Tags: php, laravel, eager-loading, laravel-5.4

I am attempting to eager load a two deep relationship (child and grandchild) with selects on both descendants. However, when I add a `addSelect()` method to the grandchild it returns an empty array. What I have is the following:

```
$products = Category::with([
   'products' => function($q){ $q->addSelect(['product_name', 'product_desc']);},
   'products.productgroup' => function($q){ $q->addSelect(['price']);}
])->where('id', 1)->get();
```

This returns the Category and the product constraints, but the productgroup is returned as an empty array.

If I run the following:

```
$products = Category::with('products', 'products.productgroup')->where('id', 1)->get();
```

I get the expected return of all data including the productgroup data. It's only when I add the `addSelect()` method to the products or products.productgroup that it returns an empty array. Is there something i'm missing here?

I can't find any similar issues on stack or the laravel forums and i'm stumped.

**EDIT:** *Including query from debugbar*

The queries that came up in the debugbar are:

```
30.55ms
select * from `categories` where `id` = '1'
29.38ms
homestead
select `product_name`, `category_product`.`category_id` as`pivot_category_id`, `category_product`.`product_id` as `pivot_product_id` from `products` inner join `category_product` on `products`.`id` = `category_product`.`product_id` where `category_product`.`category_id` in ('1')
730μs
homestead
select `price` from `product_groups` where `product_groups`.`product_id` in ('')
```

I'm not 100% on how the query builder works under the hood with eager loading. It would appear that the product id isn't getting passed to the product_groups query when a `addSelect()` is present on either the product query or the productgroup query.

Comment: Please can you post the generated query?

Comment: The results of the query?

Comment: The SQL query, You can use laravel-debugbar to view all the queries run on a page.

Comment: Ah ok. Let me just grab that and run the query again.

Comment: Edited above with query

Answer (score 3):

Ok so the answer to this is pretty simple. When selecting columns from the child and grandchild using `addSelect()`, I was not selecting the `product.id` or `productgroup.product_id`. The `product.id` and `productgroup.product_id` are obviously required in order to map the Grandchild to the Child node. It should be:

```
$products = Category::with(['products' => function($q){
    $q->with(['productgroups' => function($g){
        $g->addSelect(['id', 'price', 'product_id']);
    }])->addSelect(['id', 'product_name', 'product_desc']);
}])->where('id', 1)->get();
```

Hope this helps anyone else who encounters a grandchild node of an eager load returning an empty array.

**HT to Eddy The Dove**

I used his nested formatting which reproduced the same issue, but was syntactically cleaner than my own way.

Comment: nice you found the answer by yourself

Comment: Hey it seems you use my solution to get to your solution. just added more columns. Please be fair with other people answers in the future. You can upvote, mark it as an answer or at least mention you used someone code to get to the solution. Stack overflow works by people helping one another and getting rewarded. If there was no reward, believe me, most people wouldn't answer.

Comment: Your "solution" didn't solve the issue. You just re-wrote what I had already done in a different way. Thats not a solution and it didn't solve the issue. It returned the exact same problem (an empty array). If your answer had in any way contributed to solving the problem I would happily give credit. The solution was to request the foreign key (product_id) from productgroup and the PK (id) from products in the `addSelect()` method. You did not have this in your answer. Stack overflow works by people getting credit for solving a problem, not rewriting the OP's code in another way.

Comment: All good then. Because your "final solution" looks kinda close to mine. but with more fields

Comment: The solution was to add the missing keys in the select so that the products could be mapped to the correct productgroup. This solution also works with my original formatting so you reformatting my code from a sequential array to a nested chain wasn't the solution. I do prefer the nested chain so a HT to you for that. I just didn't mark it as a solution because it wasn't. I wasn't trying to be unfair, just realistic.

Answer (score 1):

Try like this

```
$products = Category::with(['products' => function($q){ 
    $q->with(['productgroup' => function($a) {
        $a->addSelect(['price']);
    }])->addSelect(['product_name', 'product_desc']);
})->where('id', 1)->get();
```

Comment: No that produced the same result.

Comment: Given you question I will have posted the same code of @EddyTheDove. What result do you expect?

Comment: I expect productgroup to return data (price). It returns an empty array.

Answer (score 0):

Try this if it works plz:

```
$product_ids = Category::find(1)->products()->pluck('id');
$prices = ProductGroup::whereIn('product_id', $product_ids)->pluck('price');
```

Comment: I think there is a bit of confusion here. I'm trying to eager load the child and grandchild of a category instance with constraints on the child and grandchild as a single collection.

Comment: Sorry Bill, probably I am a big dumb, but the only constrain I saw in your code is the where on the Category id.

Comment: No you're not dumb. I am. I was referring to the `addSelect()` method as a constraint as that is where you would add a constraint (like `$q->where('foo', $bar)`) on a child with eager loading. Select, of course, is not a constraint. This doesn't change the fact that adding addSelect() to a child or grandchild returns an empty array on the grandchild.

Comment: Thats ok try with a where, I think that the answer from @Eddy with the wheres instead of the addSelect should be good